# Biased single-source relaxation oscillator not starting

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, oscillator, measurement, low-voltage

Vcc is 5 V , first op-amp LM358 provides 2.5 V ground for easiest possible relaxation oscillator build with MCP661 (2.5/5.5 V supply, 60 MHz operational range). I wanted to use it to measure values of capacitors. Yet for some reason it doesn't start but hangs with the output at 2.5 V when connecting any capacitance.

Please point me towards what I might have done wrong.

[image: Biased oscillator]

Comment: Yep, this is the classic: "amplifiers do, oscillators don't" [oscillate]... ;-)

Comment: @AliChen I just don't know why ;_;

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Why shouldn't it be connected to virtual ground?

Comment: FWIW, I don't see why you have a 2.5V reference U1 will still rail at +5 and 0V under normal operation.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-complicating things and have too much hysteresis. A single rail (and single op-amp) relaxation oscillator like this will do the job: -

[image]

Notice that R3 and R4 provide the "loose" mid-rail that can be superimposed with the positive feedback from the op-amp output. This circuit has significantly lower hysteresis too because ofthe effects of both R3 and R4.

Comment: Biasing exemplary circuit seemed easies, I'll try to make single rail then.

Comment: And why are R3 and R4 not equal? The hysteresis depends also on R2; increasing it, we can do the hysteresis as small as we want.

Comment: That was just a sample picture that I had. If I were to speculate, I’d say maybe the opamp was an LM324 I.e one that doesn’t go rail to rail on the positive supply line.

Comment: Sorry, I thought so... I often use pictures from other resources and I have the problem that not everything is the same... and I have to explain that it is not exactly the same but a similar circuit diagram...

Answer (score 0):

You have too large hysteresis. Make R3 50% smaller OR double R5 and compensate by doubling R4 (only approximate compensation)

EDIT: The constant 2,5V output fits to the case that you have accidentally exchanged the inverting and non inverting inputs of U1. Quadruple check this from alternative data sources.

Comment: Tried making R3 50% smaller - still the same results.

Comment: @pholat after decreasing R3 the circuit works in simulation with much lower spec opamps than you have . Have you built this circuit? How about rf coupling capacitors? Existent or not in opam's supply pins? How are connected the unused opamps (if you have a quad)? Can you show a photo of your built circuit? 2,5V output is simply irrational if all components are alive and the circuit is connected right. Have your opamps Chip Select-input? Note that 60MHz is the theoretical Gain-bandwidth produt, the usable range is much lower.

Comment: 1: simulations are not applications, especially when ideal components are used. 2: my bad, there are no capacitors by opamp supply pins, though circuit is 3/2cm smd very close to power supply. 3: unused are unconnected 4: no, but connections were doubly checked with multimeter 5: there is no CS 6: I know that 60MHz is theoretical, that's why i point much lower.

Comment: test the aliveness of your U1. Take a 1kOhm pot or trimpot. Connet its slider to 2/J1 and the far ends to Vcc and Gnd. Check, if the state flips and is there a hysteresis when the pot is turned. Check also have you accidentally exchanged the inverting and non inverting inputs of U1 in your circuit.